# How do I Ban/un-ban users in Hamachi2?

Tags: networking, vpn, hamachi

I was using Hamachi (v1) and banned a couple of users for a week.

During this time, Hamachi auto-updated to Hamachi2, and now I can't find the ban/un-ban function.  Any idea where this is and how to un-ban a user?

I tried re-installing the Hamachi (v1) client, but when I started it, it auto-updated to v2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Right click on the user
- Click **Details...** to open the Peer Properties dialog
- Click on the **Settings** tab
- Click the **change...** link to set the **Traffic** settings for this user to **Block All**

Now you have cut them off from your network, i.e. "banned" them.  To let them back in, just set the traffic setting back to one of the other three settings based upon your security preferences (Block unsecured, Block untrusted, or Allow all).

Comment: I see this and will use it in the future, but the currently banned people cant be un-banned, as they are still using Hamachi (v1) and I can't see them in my networks....

Comment: @Paige: That is a conundrum.  You'd think there would be a way to do this through the web interface, but I sure can't find it.